# How to resolve the code if while(1){} loop is running multiple times without instruction?

Tags: c, while-loop, menu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int);
int main(void);

int main()
{
    char uc;
    int n, m, i, j, k, l, f[100000], primef[100000];

    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n\nTo CHECK whether a number is PRIME OR NOT\tENTER 'p'\n");
        printf("To DISPLAY ALL PRIME FACTORS of a number\tENTER 'f'\n");
        printf("To DISPLAY ALL FACTORS of a number\t\tENTER 'a'\n");
        printf("To DISPLAY ALL PRIME NUMBERS BEFORE a number\tENTER 'd'\n");
        printf("To EXIT\t\t\t\t\t\tENTER 'e'\n\n");
        printf("Enter: ");
        scanf("%c", &uc);

        if (uc == 'p')
        {
            printf("\n\nEnter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            if (n >= 0)
            {
                if (prime(n) == 0)
                {
                    printf("\n\n%d is NOT PRIME\n\n", n);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n\n%d is PRIME\n\n", n);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\nINVALID INPUT :(\n\n");
            }
        }

        else if (uc == 'f')
        {
            printf("\n\nEnter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            if (n >= 0)
            {
                i = 2;
                j = 1;
                k = 1;
                primef[0] = 1;
                f[0] = 1;
                m = n;
                while (i <= m)
                {
                    if (m % i == 0)
                    {
                        if (prime(i) == 1)
                        {
                            primef[j] = i;
                            f[k] = i;
                            j++;
                            k++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            f[k] = i;
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                for (l = j; l <= 100000; l++)
                {
                    primef[l] = 0;
                }
                for (l = k; l <= 100000; l++)
                {
                    f[l] = 0;
                }
                printf("\n\nPRIME FACTORS of %d are:\n", n);
                printf("%d", primef[1]);
                for (l = 2; l <= j - 1; l++)
                {
                    printf(", %d", primef[l]);
                }
                printf("\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\nINVALID INPUT :(\n\n");
            }
        }

        else if (uc == 'a')
        {
            printf("\n\nEnter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            if (n >= 0)
            {
                i = 2;
                j = 1;
                k = 1;
                m = n;
                while (i <= m)
                {
                    if (m % i == 0)
                    {
                        if (prime(i) == 1)
                        {
                            primef[j] = i;
                            f[k] = i;
                            j++;
                            k++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            f[k] = i;
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                for (l = j; l <= 100000; l++)
                {
                    primef[l] = 0;
                }
                for (l = k; l <= 100000; l++)
                {
                    f[l] = 0;
                }
                primef[0] = 1;
                f[0] = 1;
                printf("\n\nFACTORS of %d are:\n", n);
                printf("%d", f[0]);
                for (l = 1; l <= k - 1; l++)
                {
                    printf(", %d", f[l]);
                }
                printf("\n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\nINVALID INPUT :(\n\n");
            }
        }

        else if (uc == 'd')
        {
            printf("\n\nEnter a number: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            if (n >= 0)
            {
                if (n > 2)
                {
                    printf("\n\nPRIME NUMBERS BEFORE %d are:\n", n);
                    printf("%d", i = 2);
                    for (i = 2; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        if (prime(i) == 1)
                        {
                            printf(", %d", i);
                        }
                    }
                    printf("\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n\nThere are NO PRIME NUMBERS BEFORE %d\n\n", n);
                    printf("\n\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n\nINVALID INPUT :(\n\n");
                printf("\n\n");
            }
        }

        else if (uc == 'e')
        {
            printf("\n\nTHANK YOU :)\n\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("\n\nINVALID INPUT :(\n\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int prime(int a)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (a % i == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (i == a)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In the above menu-type code, I have used `while(1){}`. I was expecting following sequence of execution:

> 1. MENU appears
> 2. ASK to ENTER the CHOICE
> 3. TAKE CHOICE (say I have entered 'p')
> 4. TAKE INPUT and say WHETHER THE NUMBER IS PRIME OR NOT
> 5. AGAIN MENU APPEARS
> 6. ASK to ENTER the CHOICE

And I was expecting following output:

```
To CHECK whether a number is PRIME OR NOT       ENTER 'p'
To DISPLAY ALL PRIME FACTORS of a number        ENTER 'f'
To DISPLAY ALL FACTORS of a number              ENTER 'a'
To DISPLAY ALL PRIME NUMBERS BEFORE a number    ENTER 'd'
To EXIT                                         ENTER 'e'

Enter: p


Enter a number: 23


23 is PRIME


To CHECK whether a number is PRIME OR NOT       ENTER 'p'
To DISPLAY ALL PRIME FACTORS of a number        ENTER 'f'
To DISPLAY ALL FACTORS of a number              ENTER 'a'
To DISPLAY ALL PRIME NUMBERS BEFORE a number    ENTER 'd'
To EXIT                                         ENTER 'e'

Enter:
```

But the output is as following even if I am giving my choice only one time.

```
To CHECK whether a number is PRIME OR NOT       ENTER 'p'
To DISPLAY ALL PRIME FACTORS of a number        ENTER 'f'
To DISPLAY ALL FACTORS of a number              ENTER 'a'
To DISPLAY ALL PRIME NUMBERS BEFORE a number    ENTER 'd'
To EXIT                                         ENTER 'e'

Enter: p


Enter a number: 23


23 is PRIME

INVALID INPUT :(



To CHECK whether a number is PRIME OR NOT       ENTER 'p'
To DISPLAY ALL PRIME FACTORS of a number        ENTER 'f'
To DISPLAY ALL FACTORS of a number              ENTER 'a'
To DISPLAY ALL PRIME NUMBERS BEFORE a number    ENTER 'd'
To EXIT                                         ENTER 'e'

Enter:
```

.

Comment: Use `fgets()` for user input, forget `scanf()` exists.

Comment: Unrelated, your `prime` function test can be considerably faster by (a) only iterating to the floor of the square root of `a`, (b) testing 2 out of the loop, then starting the loop at 3 and incrementing by 2. Also, the `if` test at the end (`if (i == a)`) is pointless; the only way you reach that point in the function is if the prior loop didn't `return` early, so just `return 1;` and lose the test (which should also fix a compiler warning you're probably not configured to see).

Comment: Can you please edit the code and post, so that I will be able to get you properly. @WhozCraig

Answer (score 0):

On the *second* `scanf("%d",&n)`, you enter (e.g.) `23`. But, this has a *newline*. So, the line is: `23\n`

The newline *remains* in the input stream, so on the second loop iteration, the `scanf("%c",&c)` will get the newline (e.g. 0x0A).

With `"%c"`, `scanf` just gets the next char. With `"%d"` or `"%s"`, the `scanf` will skip over/ignore the newline

To fix, replace the first `scanf` with (e.g.):

```
char ubuf[100];
scanf("%s", ubuf);
uc = ubuf[0];
```

---

A simple way to have debugged this would have been to add a `printf` after the first `scanf`:

```
printf("DEBUG: uc=%2.2X\n",uc);
```

It would have printed:

```
DEBUG: uc=0A
```

This would have given you a clue.

---

A possibly better fix is the use `fgets` throughout and then use (e.g.) `strtol` to decode a number

Comment: THANK YOU for the effort. But I have a small doubt, how does '23' get a newline even if I am entering '23' only?

Comment: In canonical mode, the [linux] _kernel_ TTY driver will only release the data to the application (i.e. `scanf/getchar/fgets`) when a user enters newline. That's why you can use backspace to correct the line (such line editing is done in the kernel TTY layer). Your initial user sequence is: `p\n` and then `23\n` The first `scanf` will pull in the `p`. The second `scanf` will skip the newline from the "p" line and will decode `23`, but the second newline will remain in the stream. If you enter `23` but _no_ newline, the kernel will wait [forever] until you _do_ enter newline